# C# Can't convert byte to image

Tags: c#

The code works on the tutorial I've watched but not on mine.
Here's my code:

```
private void AddButton()
{        
    foreach (TblProductType category in cse.TblProductType)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = category.Description;
        btn.Size = new Size(100, 100);
        btn.ForeColor = Color.White;

        byte [] dataCategory1 = category.Productimage;
        MemoryStream stm = new MemoryStream(dataCategory1);
        btn.Image = Image.FromStream(stm);
        btn.Image = ResizeImage(btn.Image, btn.Size);

        btn.Tag = category.ProductTypes;
        flow1.Controls.Add(btn);
        this.Controls.Add(flow1);
        btn.Click += btn_Click
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Samuel and welcome to StackOverflow. You should provide us with a bit more information about the problem, like if it is a syntax error or if it simply doesn't create the image.

Comment: Can you please share the code for ResizeImage

Comment: _Doesn't work_ is not a helpful problem description!

Answer (score 0):

We may need a little more surrounding code, or a more information to the exact nature of your problem, but i suspect the most likely cause of this issue is whatever is happening in ResizeImage.

Here's a function which resizes a `System.Drawing.Image`, perhaps give that a try and see if it fixes your problem?

```
    public static Image ResizeImage(int newWidth, int newHeight, Image image) {

        int sourceWidth = image.Width;
        int sourceHeight = image.Height;

        //Consider vertical pics
        if (sourceWidth < sourceHeight) {
            int buff = newWidth;

            newWidth = newHeight;
            newHeight = buff;
        }

        int sourceX = 0, sourceY = 0, destX = 0, destY = 0;
        float percent = 0, percentW = 0, percentH = 0;

        percentW = ((float)newWidth / (float)sourceWidth);
        percentH = ((float)newHeight / (float)sourceHeight);
        if (percentH < percentW) {
            percent = percentH;
            destX = System.Convert.ToInt16((newWidth -
                      (sourceWidth * percent)) / 2);
        } else {
            percent = percentW;
            destY = System.Convert.ToInt16((newHeight -
                      (sourceHeight * percent)) / 2);
        }

        int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * percent);
        int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * percent);


        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight,
                      PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        bitmap.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution,
                     image.VerticalResolution);

        Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        graphic.Clear(Color.Black);
        graphic.InterpolationMode =
            System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        graphic.DrawImage(image,
            new Rectangle(destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight),
            new Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight),
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        graphic.Dispose();
        image.Dispose();
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this:
In my problem I saved my chart to an memoryStream.. then saved that memoryStream to byte array and then saved byte array to an image. It works for me.

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            //saved my chart to an memoryStream
            Chart2.SaveImage(memoryStream, ChartImageFormat.Png);

            //saved memorystream to byte array
            byte[] byteArrayIn = memoryStream.ToArray();

            //saving byte back to an Image
            Image image1 = new Image();
            image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteArrayIn, 0, byteArrayIn.Length);

            newChart.Controls.Add(image1);
            divRadarChart.Visible = false;
        }
```